# jQuery toggle not working on existing records

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2007

I have a SP2007 form called editItem. I have found that when sharePoint renders formfields, there is an attribute- title- which holds the contents of the SharePoint fieldname attribute.

My issue is with some of the controls in this edit form. I have a drop down control called anonymous, that toggles the visibility of name and email input fields; however, when I edit an existing record that ‘Yes’ has been selected, it still shows the name and email input fields, instead of hiding them as they should be.

Also, b/c they are now visible it doesn't seem to mak any difference if I change the anonymous field's value...

Here’s the script I wrote:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  if $("select[title='anonymous'] option:selected").val() == "Yes" {

alert("$('select[title='anonymous']').val()"); 

     //$("tr.anon").hide();

  //} else {

    // $("[title='anonymous']").change(function(){
     //   $(".anon").toggle();
    // });
  }
 });
</script>
```

Here’s the src from the form:

```
<tr><td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>Anonymous<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span></nobr></H3></td><td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody"><span dir="none"><select name="ctl00$m$g_e959bdad_1c52_41a7_b23f_564bc84c2497$ff5_1$ctl00$DropDownChoice" id="ctl00_m_g_e959bdad_1c52_41a7_b23f_564bc84c2497_ff5_1_ctl00_DropDownChoice" title="anonymous" class="ms-RadioText">
                    <option selected="selected" value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>

                </select><br></span>Would you like to remain anonymous?</td></tr><tr class="anon"><td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>Name</nobr></H3></td><td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody"><span dir="none">
        <input name="ctl00$m$g_e959bdad_1c52_41a7_b23f_564bc84c2497$ff6_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" type="text" maxlength="255" id="ctl00_m_g_e959bdad_1c52_41a7_b23f_564bc84c2497_ff6_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="name" class="ms-long" /><br>
    </span></td></tr><tr class="anon"><td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><H3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>Email</nobr></H3></td><td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody"><span dir="none">
        <input name="ctl00$m$g_e959bdad_1c52_41a7_b23f_564bc84c2497$ff7_1$ctl00$ctl00$TextField" type="text" maxlength="255" id="ctl00_m_g_e959bdad_1c52_41a7_b23f_564bc84c2497_ff7_1_ctl00_ctl00_TextField" title="email" class="ms-long" /><br>
    </span></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap><table><tr><td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap><IMG SRC="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18"></td><td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap>
        <TABLE cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=100%><TR><TD align="right"  width=100% nowrap>
            <input type="button" name="ctl00$m$g_e959bdad_1c52_41a7_b23f_564bc84c2497$savebutton2$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem" value="OK" onclick="if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$m$g_e959bdad_1c52_41a7_b23f_564bc84c2497$savebutton2$ctl00$diidIOSaveItem&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))" id="ctl00_m_g_e959bdad_1c52_41a7_b23f_564bc84c2497_savebutton2_ctl00_diidIOSaveItem" accesskey="O" class="ms-ButtonHeightWidth" target="_self" />
        </TD> </TR>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is messed up.

```
if $("select[title='anonymous'] option:selected").val() == "Yes" {
```

You didn't wrap your condition in parens:

```
if ($("select[title='anonymous'] option:selected").val() == "Yes") {
```

You also don't need the `option:selected` part.  You can just get the `val` of the select:

```
if ($("select[title='anonymous']").val() == "Yes") {
```

Comment: Thanks James. Do you know of  any sites where I could brush up on my syntax?

Comment: Not specifically.  Any javascript tutorial should do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working code. You can take a look at this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/STvWX/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($("select[title='anonymous']").val() == "Yes") { 
     $("tr.anon").hide();
  }
  $("select[title='anonymous']").change(function(){
     $("tr.anon").toggle();
  });
});
```

First off, as James said, you need to wrap the conditional. Then, check the value and hide the `tr` if val is "Yes".

Then, **outside of the conditional**, you need to apply your change handler. That way, it gets applied whether or not the conditional is true.